# Assuming $f(n)$ is non-decreasing and $f(n) = n^2$ where $n$ is odd, then $f(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Assuming $f(n)$ is a non-decreasing function and $f(n) = n^2$ where $n$ is odd, then $f(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$ i.e. $\exists c_1, c_2, n_0 \in \mathbb{R^{\geq 0}}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n > n_0 \Rightarrow c_1 \cdot n^2 \leq f(n) \leq c_2 \cdot n^2 $. How do I go about this proof given assuming we only know that when $n$ is odd and nothing is given for when it is even. Is it possible to prove this using the floor function?

Any help would be appreciated and if you could prove this using the floor function especially, it would help me understand how to prove Big-Theta proofs.

Comment: Could you include the definition of $\Theta(n^2)$ in the question?

Comment: Of course! Let me add it right now.

Comment: Also, the value of $n_0$ is usually based on an $n_1$ and $n_2$(they could also be equal) for each side of the inequality.

Comment: Well, it's none decreasing so if $2n - 1 < x < 2n +1$ then $(2n-1)^2 \le f(x) \le (2n+ 1)$.  Does that help at all.